# setting and array of params in rails

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3.2

A series of objects need to be purchased in a single transaction, however each item must be a different transaction object due to relationship issues.

A confirmation action aims to list each of these items independently.  The controller attempts to prepare parameters for viewing each transaction

```
<% @transactions.each do |transaction| %>
  <%= params[:product_id][:product_id] %>
[...]
```

as follows:

```
@transactions = params[:product_ids].map do |product_id|
  @transaction = Transaction.new
  @inventories = Inventory.where(['product_id = ?', product_id]).all
  @my_price = my_price
  params[:product_id][:product_id] = product_id  # sanity check
  params[:product_id][:additional_info] = session[:additional_info]
  params[:product_id][:rate] = @inventories.map(&@my_price).inject(0, :+)
end
@sub_total = @transactions.params[:product_id][:rate].sum
```

However `undefined method []= for nil:NilClass` is generated when building the params for each product_id.  This command is obviously mistaken.  [The approach could also be inefficient/ineffective...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you don't really mean `params[:product_id][:product_id]`, but rather `params[product_id][:product_id]`, since `:product_id` is a symbol, *not* a variable.

When setting a new hash in the hash, you need to first define it as such:

```
params[product_id] = {}
params[product_id][:product_id] = product_id
# ...
```

This should resolve the `undefined method []= for nil:NilClass`. I guess you will encounter some more problems (like `@inventories.map(&@my_price)`) after you fix this one though...

---

With some guesswork, I guess a code which does what you want will look something like this:

```
@transactions = params[:product_ids].map do |product_id|
  transaction = Transaction.new
  transaction.product_id = product_id  # sanity check
  transaction.additional_info = session[:additional_info]
  transaction.rate = Inventory.where(['product_id = ?', product_id]).sum(:my_price)
  transaction
end
@sub_total = @transactions.map(&:rate).sum
```

And the view would be something like this:

```
<% @transactions.each do |transaction| %>
  <%= transaction.product_id %>
[...]
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I did mean `params[product_id][...]` and had tried that with unhappy result.  Your answer did resolve the indefined method.  However in the view it returns `undefined local variable or method "product_id"`

Comment: the variable `product_id` comes from `params[:product_ids].map do |product_id|`. In the view there is no `product_id` variable, only `transaction` variable (from `@transactions.each do |transaction|`)

Comment: We crossed paths asynchronously! posted without seeing edit... However `undefined method 'product_id' for #<BigDecimal`

Comment: @Jerome in your original code, the `@transactions` array contains a list of the `rate` values (the return value of the last line of the `map` block). I suggest you should check all my suggestion, and see if it suits you better.

Comment: I see what I missed and where I got sidetracked.  Working on your suggestion!

Comment: Proper result; good guesswork (my_price was a blind alley in any instance)!

Comment: Your suggestion is different than the syntax I usually employ (dependent on params and session values). Assuming the view is a form with `<%= form_for :transaction, :url => create_multiple_transactions_path, :html => {:method => :put } do |f| %>` the controller action `create_multiple` calls up empty @transactions `@transactions.each do |transaction| transaction.save
end` how can the controller efficiently access the array, aside from `<%= fields_for` and a bunch of invisible values?